# Calculating Value At Risk or "most probable loss", for a given distribution of returns

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, scipy, quantitative-finance

Given historical daily returns, how can I calculate the portfolio allocation for a single stock position, based on not losing more than 10% of the starting portfolio value over 21 days? (with 95% confidence.)

Based on some starting code of e.g.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm

returns = [-0.01, -0.02, -0.01, 0.04, 0.02, 0.01, -0.03]
mu = np.mean(returns)
std = np.std(returns)
valueAtRisk = norm.ppf(0.05, mu, sigma)
```

However, the above only tells me my risk for 1 day. My question goes in the other direction; what can I allocate given the distribution of returns, assuming that I don't want to lose more than 10% over 21 days.

I would prefer an answer that can be computed directly, but a Monte Carlo answer would be acceptable.

Thanking you kindly for your help.

Comment: This might be a better question for CrossValidated, but isn't there a matrix operation that will compound the distribution of returns for n days?

Comment: I'd like a python/scipy type solution (and I'm not sure I'd understand a purely statistics-based answer). The problem is `norm.ppf(0.05, mu, sigma)` gives an idea of a 'bad day', but we're not expecting 21 purely bad days all in a row given the normal distribution.

Comment: Could you please accept my answer if my approach helps you solve the problem? Many thanks.

Answer (score 6):

```
import numpy as np

returns = np.random.randn(1000)
```

Assuming returns are independently and identically distributed (i.i.d.), then the volatility of T days equals to the product of sqrt(T) times one-day-volatility.

```
# one-way 5% quantile, critical value is 1.64
VaR_21 = returns.std() * np.sqrt(21) * 1.645
VaR_21
Out[72]: 7.4161618430166989
```

Alternatively, you can do bootstraps. That's randomly select 21 days from historical dataset, calculate the return over this randomly drawed 21 days. Plot the histogram and get the 5% quantile.

```
def generate_random_index(n=21):
    # could set replace to False as well
    return np.random.choice(np.arange(1000), size=n, replace=False)  

VaR_simulated_21 = []
n_bootstrap = 10000
for _ in range(n_bootstrap):
    VaR = returns[generate_random_index(21)].sum()
    VaR_simulated_21.append(VaR)

plt.hist(VaR_simulated_21)
np.percentile(VaR_simulated_21, q=5)
Out[108]: -8.0686958215041216
```

[image]

Comment: would it not be `VaR = (1+returns[generate_random_index(21)]).cumprod()[-1]` ?